# The '<' symbol automatically starts typing repeatedly everytime in linux

Tags: keyboard

I've not spilled any liquid on the keyboard and the keys are in good condition. The symbol starts typing on its own when the keyboard is ideal and also repeats when I type anything from keyboard. 
This is making my laptop unresponsive and it gets kind of hanged. Please help me get rid of the problem!

Comment: Try another keyboard and see!

Answer (score 1):

This seems very likely to be a "stuck" key, and if not due to foreign material holding a key, likely indicates a hardware failure.  Since it's a laptop, it's not as simple as unplugging the keyboard and trying another one, but if the machine isn't too old, it's possible to get a replacement keyboard (either install yourself or pay someone to install it).

Before spending money, however, try booting from a Live medium, just to verify that it's hardware and not a bizarre glitch in your keyboard driver.  That's very unlikely, but all it costs to check is the time to burn a flash drive with an Ubuntu ISO.

Comment: more like a comment, isn't it? I'm not sure

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh It looks fine to me. Stuck keyboard, or try Live DVD/USB.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my '<' typing problem with a system update.

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)